# Doing several UART transmissions at the same time

Tags: stm32, nucleo

I am trying to transmit three (65535 bytes) buffers through a UART. I just want to transmit all of them.

The main buffer is separated into three buffers. When I tried to transmit all of them I was be able to transmit only DATA1.

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
#define MAX_FRAME_SIZE 196605
#define FRAME 65535
/* USER CODE END PD */
/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
static uint8_t aFull_Buffer[MAX_FRAME_SIZE];
static uint8_t DATA1[FRAME];
static uint8_t DATA2[FRAME];
static uint8_t DATA3[FRAME];
/* USER CODE END PV */
/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM1_Init(void);
static void MX_USB_OTG_FS_PCD_Init(void);
static void MX_USART3_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
static void TransferComplete(DMA_HandleTypeDef *hdma_tim1_ch1);
int main(void) {
  HAL_DMA_Start_IT(htim1.hdma[TIM_DMA_ID_CC1], GPIOC_IDR, (uint32_t) &aFull_Buffer, MAX_FRAME_SIZE);
 
  // Enable timer to trigger DMA transfer - CC1DE bit
  __HAL_TIM_ENABLE_DMA(&htim1, TIM_DMA_CC1);
 
  // Enable timer input capture
  HAL_TIM_IC_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
  while (1) {}}
 
static void TransferComplete(DMA_HandleTypeDef *hdma_tim1_ch1) {
  for (i = 0; i < 65534; i++) {
    DATA1[j]=aFull_Buffer[i]
    DATA2[j]=aFull_Buffer[i+FRAME]
    DATA3[j]=aFull_Buffer[i+FRAME+FRAME+FRAME];
    j++;
  }

  HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(&huart3,DATA1,FRAME);
  HAL_Delay (3000);
  HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(&huart3,DATA2,FRAME);
  HAL_Delay (3000);
  HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(&huart3,DATA3,FRAME);
  HAL_Delay (3000); 
}
```

Comment: OK. And you have debugged the error being what exactly? And baud rate is? Have you checked 3 seconds is enough time to transmit 65536 bytes?

Comment: yes it is enough, I received 65535 data with 115200 baudrate

Comment: No it isn't, as in 3 seconds you can only transfer 34560 bytes.

Comment: If you don't want your code to do anything else while the bytes are being sent, then why not simply call `HAL_UART_Transmit(...)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 seconds is not enough to transfer 65536 bytes at 115200 bps.

Therefore only first 64k transmission starts, but it is still ongoing when transmission of next block should start, so it fails. You would see that if you would look at what error the function returns when you try to use it.